# utl_lms.format_message | PL/SQL | URL correct in <a> but dot is missing in href

Tags: oracle, email, plsql, bitstuffing, formatmessage

I'm trying to send a mail with a link inside.

```sql
l_url := 'https://example.test.com/';
l_body :=  utl_lms.format_message('<body><a href="%s">%s</a></body>', l_url, l_url);
```

But here's what I have as result :

```html
<body><a href="https://example.testcom/">https://example.test.com/</a></body>
```

Why the "." is missing in the href...?

**UPDATE**

I have countered this problem. It works, but it **doesn't solve it**.

```sql
l_url := 'https://example.test..com/';
l_body :=  utl_lms.format_message('<body><a href="%s">%s</a></body>', l_url, replace(l_url, '..', '.'));
```

Result :

```html
<body><a href="https://example.test.com/">https://example.test.com/</a></body>
```

Comment: The code seems correct. Maybe post the whole code so we can check if you are modifying the values somewhere.

Comment: Well, you already have the whole code :/
I'm just sending a mail with this body...

Comment: I tested it on my environment and it works correctly. Check it here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=de6bf928140cfce90878568ec8f434bb

Comment: Yes... I see... But it's not what I get actually :'(